# Bluetooth dongle suddenly dissapears

Tags: usb, bluetooth

A bluetooth dongle attached to my banana pi suddenly dissapears from the usb devices list. Lsusb doesnt show it at all, but maybe this is interesting, a piece from dmesg:

`[   14.777099] udevd[167]: starting version 175
[   17.763916] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   32.983934] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   33.204856] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using sw-ehci
[   48.313924] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   63.533915] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   63.754857] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using sw-ehci
[   74.184102] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 5, error -110
[   74.294880] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using sw-ehci
[   84.724105] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 6, error -110
[   84.741575] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 3`

lsusb -t gives:
`/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=sw-ohci/1p, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=sw-ehci/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=sw-ohci/1p, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=sw-ehci/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=rtl8812au, 480M`

while "normal" lsusb gives:
`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 7392:a812 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd`

I use Linux version 3.4.104-bananian on Banana Pi 1.

How can I return back this device. It is not possible to go there because it is mounted very high ...

Comment: Please specify which model of banana pi, which OS/distro, and also a `lsusb`. If you do a reboot, can you do an `lsusb` for a while?

Comment: Nothing changes after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case the problem was solved by loading btusb module which was missing for some reason.

So:

`modprobe btusb
reboot`